# Setting an ActionListener for a Jbutton "class"

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I am remaking a menu for one of my games where to make buttons I use a method called `addButton**(text, Image, pressedImage, container)`. My problem is that I want to use the `addActionListener` method and allow each button to have their own action but I'm unable to do so. Any ideas?

This is the Menu code:

```
public Menu(Component component) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("CityBlock 2d Launcher");
        frame.setSize(new Dimension(1050, 700));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(component);

        // Set up the content pane.
        try {
            frame.setContentPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(ImageIO
                    .read(new File("res/menuBackground.png")))));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        addComponentsToPane(frame.getContentPane());

        // Display the window.
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void addComponentsToPane(Container pane) {
        pane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(pane, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        addAButton("SP", "res/Singleplayer.png",
                "res/Singleplayer_pressed.png", pane);

        addAButton("MP", "res/Multiplayer.png", "res/Multiplayer_Pressed.png",
                pane);

        addAButton("HTP", "res/HowToPlay.png", "res/HowToPlay_Pressed.png",
                pane);

        addAButton("O", "res/Options.png", "res/Options_Pressed.png", pane);

        addAButton("Q", "res/Quit.png", "res/Quit_Pressed.png", pane);

    }

private static void addAButton(final String text, String BtnIcon,
            String PressBtnIcon, Container container) {

        ImageIcon myImage = new ImageIcon(BtnIcon);

        final JButton button = new JButton(/* myImage */text);

        button.setIcon(myImage);

        button.setOpaque(false);
        button.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        button.setBorderPainted(false);

        button.setAlignmentX(Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
        button.setAlignmentY(Component.TOP_ALIGNMENT);

        button.setPressedIcon(new ImageIcon(PressBtnIcon));
        container.add(button);

        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (button.equals(text)) { <------ **Text** could probably be used to separate the different buttons????
                    // Execute when button is pressed
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }

        });
    }
}
```

Comment: [`ActionEvent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionEvent.html) object (you name it `e`) has inherited [`getSource()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EventObject.html#getSource()) method.

Comment: I would like to target all the buttons separately without complicated code. But i can't because they are technically the same button. How can it be done?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are expecting to happen when you compare a `JButton` to a `String` here: `button.equals(text)`, but I can bet that it is probably not what you want and I think it always going to evaluate to `false`. Did you mean to do `button.getText().equals(text)`?

Comment: `( (JButton) e.getSource() ).getText()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a name for your button passed in as a parameter. Then set the name of the button and use it to compare if that was the source for the ActionEvent. Then use a private class for ActionListener rather than an anonymous class.

```
private static void addAButton(final String text, String BtnIcon,
        String PressBtnIcon, Container container, String name) {

  button.setName(name);
  button.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
  ....
}
```

put your ActionListener class outside of the method in the same class.

```
// In the Menu class
private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener{
  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    if(((JButton) e.getSource()).getName().equals(nameOfButton)){
      //do something
    }
   else if(((JButton)e.getSource()).getName().equals(nameOfDifferentButton)){
      //do something different
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One approach would be to pass the ActionListener into addAButton(), i.e.

```
private static void addAButton(final String text, String BtnIcon,
        String PressBtnIcon, Container container, ActionListener actionListener) {
```

Then call with

```
addAButton("SP", "res/Singleplayer.png",
            "res/Singleplayer_pressed.png", pane, 
   new ActionListener() {
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           // do stuff
       }
   });

addAButton("MP", "res/Multiplayer.png", "res/Multiplayer_Pressed.png",, pane, 
   new ActionListener() {
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           // do different stuff
       }
   });
```

Another approach is to embrace Swing fully and use java.swing.Action by using it to define the icon, button text etc, then just setting on the JButton using setAction()

```
JButton button = new JButton();
Action foo = new AbstractAction() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // do stuff
    }
};
foo.putValue(Action.NAME, "Button text");
foo.putValue(Action.LARGE_ICON_KEY, new ImageIcon("res/foo.png"));
button.setAction(foo);
```